# Setting QueryOptions on a string CQL query in Spring data cassandra 2.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I will have to set query options on the string CQL query in spring-data-cassandra-2.0.7.RELEASE

```
CassandraOperations cOps = new CassandraTemplate(session); 
String cqlQuery = "insert into......."
cOps.getCqlOperations().execute(cqlQuery);
```

Is there a way to apply QueryOptions to the string input query? Also I dont want to convert to statement and then apply the options. As the use case is the input cqlQuery can be any statement.

Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

There's no support for `QueryOptions` through `CqlTemplate`. `QueryOptions` are only usable with `CassandraTemplate` (`AsyncCassandraTemplate`, `ReactiveCassandraTemplate`).

## Explanation

`CqlTemplate` is a CQL-only API abstraction that aligns with Spring Framework's `JdbcTemplate`. You can configure some options on `CqlTemplate`-level, such as `ConsistencyLevel`, `FetchSize`, and `RetryPolicy`.

If you want to control query options, use Datastax' `Statement` objects (such as `SimpleStatement`):

```
SimpleStatement statement = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO …");
statement.setFetchSize(1234);
statement.setRetryPolicy(FallthroughRetryPolicy.INSTANCE);
// probably more …

execute(statement);
```

Comment: My input query is like below:  ********* BEGIN BATCH insert into person(name, age, id) values ('Roby',24,'123963011') USING TIMESTAMP 1529300306789000 AND TTL 60;insert into person(name, age, id) values ('Jefferson',23,'123963012') USING TIMESTAMP 1529300306789000 AND TTL 60; APPLY BATCH;  ******* Above fix does not work for my case. Any idea how to accomplish for above string based query. The string input can be a single update/insert/delete statement or multiple of its kind. Appreciate the reply @mp911de . Thanks